# Specify coordinates with the rectangle select tool in Paint.NET

Tags: paint.net, microsoft-paint

In paint.net, suppose I have an image that is 1920x1080. Is there a way to use the rectangle select tool to enter specific cords (e.g. 300,300,600,600) and have the rectangle selector appear there on the image? To which then, you are free to press CTRL + C to copy that section.

The way I currently do it is by tediously positioning the cursor at the specified coordinates and slowly inch them to get the box right where I want it.